# How can i call from php and write the result in a specific place in html code without the need of passing variables

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am facing a situation that I don't know how to proceed I will try to be clear about what I want to do: here it goes I have 2 files one called index.php (where it's almost all of it HTML code) other indexphp.php where I'm handling PHP code, connecting to DB etc.

here's a print screen of my index.php, this is supposed to be a dashboard that you access after logging in in the application (where I am nesting my HTML code)

dashboard

I am using this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['nivel_user'])){ 
    header('Location: /php/logout.php');
} else {
    $tu =  $_SESSION['nivel_user'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['idformador'];
    $username = $_SESSION['user'];
}
```

Session variables in both index.php and indexphp.php and I want it to show different queries according to my login (I have different types of access levels) the results of my queries are supposed to be shown in that dashboard instead of those numbers you see at the top of that print screen, right now there are static values and I want them to be dynamic according to my queries.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work. (Note: Those queries need to be updated on page load since after logging in I automatically access the dashboard)

```js
$(document ).ready(function(){
$('#query1').load('indexphp.php'){
```

```html
 <div class="row tile_count">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
      <div class="count" id="query1">2</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">100% </i> </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand, but I guess you can perform ajax request to your php scripts?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: yea i guess i can basically i am using that session_start() in all my .php files, i want to show my queries on page load that i am handling in my indexphp.php where i am pointing out in that printscreen . I don't know what's the best way to do this i am a bit puzzled and i don't have much experience with JQuery and ajax. By the way i don't need to pass variables to my indexphp.php file i just need to call it in my <div class="count" id="query1">2</div> where "2" is a static value for example and i want to show the result of a query